# Open a web browser using C# win application and add request headers in the request

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient

I have a situation where I want to simulate a web request which comes to application. It contains some url values and Request Headers.

I know that I can start a browser using

```
var url = "http://test.com";
var sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(url);
Process.Start(sInfo);
```

But I want to add some header values in the url which I want to open in browser.
I have tried using different things but not able to open it in browser.

I have used `WebClient` as below

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
var url = "http://test.com";
client.Headers.Add("USER", "ABC");
string text=client.DownloadString(url);
```

But how to use this string in web browser I don't know.

I have also tried `WebBrowser` but not able to simulate.

Comment: Why? Are you trying to test some HTTP API? Would something like Postman work for you?

Comment: @luaan actually i want to simulate a request which comes to my application's page asp.net and in which there are request

Comment: Yes, you're talking about simulating a request. But how is it actually used when you're not *simulating*, but actually *using* the web application? Obviously, it's not by a web browser, otherwise you'd already have your solution. What do you want in return, and what do you do with the response?

Comment: @Luaan the request come from a link anchor tag it comes via a ldap server where they add some parameter in request header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard for this. If you want to pass custom headers, you need to consult the web browser you are using. I don't think any of the major browsers have such a feature, though - however, there extensions for both Chrome and Firefox that allow you to *globally* add headers to every request. Maybe that's good enough for you, maybe not.

Comment: Thanks for your help I have used firefox addon and it worked form me.

Comment: i am in search of similar functionality. @शेखर can you please let me know, what extension you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided I see three options to get close to what you want:

#### Set the DocumentText of the webbrowser control

If you have a raw html text you can set the property [`DocumentText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext(v=vs.110).aspx) of the webBrowser control to render that. The control takes care of loading additional resources but it fails to load resources that are relative to the document source. But this might not be an issue for your use case.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
client.Headers.Add("USER", "ABC");
string text = client.DownloadString(url);

this.webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
this.webBrowser1.DocumentText = text;
```

#### Use the Navigate method

The [`Navigate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161356(v=vs.110).aspx) method has an overload that takes an additional header parameter.

```
this.webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com", 
                           null, 
                           new byte[]{}, 
                          "USER: ABC;");
```

[Here is what the headers will look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLPqR.png)

#### Use CsQuery

If you're only interested in parts of the returned html and can afford spending time scraping that html and build-up your own UI you can leverage [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) that is a jQuery port to .Net.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
client.Headers.Add("USER", "ABC");
string text = client.DownloadString(url);

var csdoc = CsQuery.CQ.CreateDocument(text);

foreach(var q in csdoc.Find("a.question-hyperlink"))
{
    Debug.WriteLine(q.InnerText);
}
```